# Preview Pane Not Displaying Correct Formatting

Tags: c1-cms

I am using C1 3 and am having problems with the preview pane.

The C1 site uses master pages for templates, and works correctly when published. However, it is not displaying correctly in the preview pane. It visually appears to be ignoring CSS settings.

This site was copied from an original install, on another sever, that works correctly.

Any tips and or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE****
In the content view, which is not working, it is using this url
http://www.abc.com/Composite/content/Frontend/Images/logo.gif

All other sites, including the published version of the site above use this url
http://cms.abc.dev/Frontend/Images/logo.gif

I am assuming the same is happening for all images and style sheet references.
However, I cannot find where this is happening. In the master page items are referenced as follows:

- href="~/Frontend/Styles/layout.css"
- ImageUrl="~/Frontend/Images/logo.gif"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the problem...

I created a new app pool, used it, and now it works.

I guess the app pool somehow got corrupted...

Answer (score 0):

Thats weird... have you somehow accidently configured the /Composite/Content folder as an application? Thats almost the only explanation why asp.net would expand ~ to /Composite/content/ instead of just /.

The preview-tab is handled through a wrapper-page that lives inside /Composite/content, unlike normal viewing of published pages which is handles by the root itself.